# Can I write a .zip consisting of TemporaryFiles?

Tags: python, zip, temporary-files

I have a program that will output a .zip file consisting of a number of .html files to the user. I don't need the .html files to exist anywhere outside of the .zip, so my thought was to make them TemporaryFiles using the tempfile module. How do I write a .zip of TempFile (assuming that's possible)?

If I can, can I also specify the names of the TemporaryFiles, so that when the user decompresses the .zip, the files will have readable names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to create a zip file is to store every required files (your HTML) files in a (temporary) directory. Then you can compress the directory.

Say, you store your ZIP file in `work_dir` and you a a function `write_html` used to write your HTML file, you can compress your HTML files like this:

```
import os
import shutil
import tempfile
import zipfile

work_dir = "..."
zip_path = os.path.join(work_dir, "delivery.zip")

zip_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
try:
    with zipfile.zipfile(zip_path, "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zfd:
        for html_name in html_names:
            html_path = os.path.join(zip_dir, html_name)
            write_html(html_path, html_name)
            zfd.write(html_path, html_name)
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(zip_dir)
```